# MNIST model predicting test images incorrectly even though it had high training and testing accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, keras, mnist

I'm trying to create a model which can predict handwritten digits. I've trained a Keras model with the architecture below and saw an accuracy of near 99% during testing. However, I decided to take some pictures off the internet of some black & white numbers and minimize their size to 28x28 with OpenCV to try and use my trained model to predict them. After testing all 10 digits, my model predicted only 4/10 correctly, meaning that it had a 40% score.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Here is the MNIST dataset I'm using: 
https://www.kaggle.com/oddrationale/mnist-in-csv

Here are the images I'm testing:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G0CMK0ZPI1JIX2cYXNRt3Qsq_YpjlMjX

```
#architecture
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

```
#Code for minmizing
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.resize(img,(28,28))

#turning the 28x28 array into a (1, 28, 28, 1) numpy array for the model to process
#dividing each value by 255. During the training, each grayscale pixel value was treated the same way

for i in range(28):
    temp = []
    for x in range(28):
        temp.append([img[i][x]/255])
    pendo.append(temp)
img = np.array([pendo]).astype("float32")

#predicting the image
model = load_model('MNIST.h5')
classes = model.predict(img)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MNIST is not a dataset meant to learn a completely general digit recognition model, its just an academic benchmark, a very old one, so getting any kind of test accuracy close to 99% is very easy and it does not mean that the model will generalize at all.

In the end this is not a programming problem, and that should be clear, its not a problem in the code, its a problem with the data. The images you have are just too different from the ones in the MNIST training set.

Comment: So are there better datasets available for handwritten digit recognition ?